# как вручную добавить файл для apt update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Устанавливаю Steam. При установке возникает такая ошибка

`libegl1:i386 : Depends: libegl-mesa0:i386 but it is not installable`

`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Нагуглил что необходимо выполнить сперва две опции

`sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse"`

и

`sudo apt update` + `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

В общем когда я пытаюсь выполнить `sudo apt update` у меня выбивает ошибку

`Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.188.87 80]` 
Я попытался перейти по указанному адресу напрямую через брузер, но такой страницы как оказалось не существует, зато с пометкой `jammy` есть другая

`http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease` 
Вопрос: как заствить команду `apt update` считывать `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease`  - может можно как-то вручную его прописать???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно зеркало под санкциями. Поправь /etc/apt/sources.list , /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list убрав нерабочие строки. Добавь зеркало поближе

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main universe multiverse"

sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main universe multiverse"
```